# Tabbar on a page - Metro App

Tags: c#, xaml, tabs, microsoft-metro, tabbar

I want to create a tabbar on a page; the tabbar consist of 2 or more buttons that load different content (forms or tables) on the same page.
How can I accomplish that? 
Thank you.

I have downloaded some projects examples from Microsoft Windows store apps development section; some of them have a simil tabbar solution. I'm studying the code but I would like to have some alternatives in terms of examples or documentation.

Comment: Can you point to the sample projects you've downloaded, so we can see what you're trying to accomplish/replicate? Or can you post a link to an illustration of what you're trying to accomplish? More details would help us understand better what your goal is...tabbed interfaces aren't terribly common in Windows Store apps, so you may also want to consider another way to accomplish the same goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this solution is reasonable: http://blog.davemdavis.net/2012/10/03/simulating-a-tab-control-in-a-windows-8-application/ You may need to tweak it. But he's done a lot of the work for you.

If it were me I would do something more like this:

```
<Grid Width="400" Height="500">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="SteelBlue" />
    <ListBox x:Name="ItemList" Margin="0,50,0,0"
                xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="10" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <sys:String>One</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Two</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Three</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Four</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Five</sys:String>
    </ListBox>
    <!-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742554(v=vs.85).aspx -->
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="LightSteelBlue" x:Name="RightArea" />
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ItemList}" 
            Style="{StaticResource ContentControlStyle2}" Grid.Column="1">
        <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="300" Height="500">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="40" 
                        FontSize="50" Foreground="Black" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

That would look something like this:

[image]

Good luck!